# How to unlist(Remove) number from truecaller with using script?

Tags: python, web-scraping, sdk

Hey Guys I am trying to (remove) unlist number from Truecaller using following link
https://www.truecaller.com/unlisting
I want to automate this process but because of recaptcha of google the requests are limited and cant possible so it it any way to do this using any library like unofficial libraries of Truecaller like Trunofficial .

Answer (score 0):

https://www.truecaller.com/unlisting
Unlisting your phone number requires reCaptcha, you can bypass it.
This my be helpful

```py
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://asia-south1-truecaller-web.cloudfunctions.net/api/noneu/unlist/v1"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer null"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Length"] = "612"
headers["accept"] = "*/*"
headers["sec-gpc"] = "1"
headers["origin"] = "https://www.truecaller.com"
headers["sec-fetch-site"] = "cross-site"
headers["sec-fetch-mode"] = "cors"
headers["sec-fetch-dest"] = "empty"
headers["referer"] = "https://www.truecaller.com/"
headers["accept-encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br"
headers["accept-language"] = "en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"

data = {
    "phoneNumber": "+919912345678",
    "recaptcha": "03ANYolqtbEiFqaQ8wBrDF3kKqkCzIaH4r79oA2hCNd80gZGENvff9fPKocccytf6QXpPvQfQ12WMvgfdP1IKggff6lTY_0ucZxFB7r6A_dbNjfp_NSYtrkU4NX1h_LBQgnCO0ALkWS8CMjaIEjhxclfeClFv4EmFNEQis1OvrSVgvB8nJipuUxGakpa0eB8yWrEQCUfy0Gs7VA2hO4VaeLRTwr6BaxYsJsCP_3-vaMP2crZDDrIm8on_0H0vqh-1S44y69b0rSM6_ornuVZxeNQkpe_3NvPjQQxqQtdyQl
d55OQkK67PH7OH_A7s3GVgMa0VCOuX_UdBsPkd8mKf708GgutggfggvVrbe3DrBsUnpXMYchsv_revkhknej0G_SxAtqtwQoGPtt5iKSKHRmlelDJpYuQs6Lwi-4Umn_E
clRPT2iaohxZ3r8O_4jaGP9yhRiMyVkgTm6mutJn50nPFbyabjSqgC2ShlMEI7IoOqWp9g90b2bl4qw4h6k9vP4AVy36sCx2z_gksBEgxT1zsM3P77PQ_guo12k7rtFlUAmvdqhqgwowaKQFMMBfjWDo40"
}


resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(resp.json())

# {
#     "lastUpdated": "2022-07-11T03:27:30.306713Z",
#     "phoneNumber": "919912345678",
#     "status": "unlisted"
# }
```